# Bootstrap - How to properly reposition my dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive website using bootstrap. The navigation menu should collapse when the window becomes very small. The issue is that when it collapses and I expand the menu it looks very bad because it is not properly positionned.

[This is the "normal" view when nothing is collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeGO8.png)

[This is when it is collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpux1.png)

[When I now expand the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHkFd.png)

And the last picture shows the issue. I'd like to be able to reposition the menu so that it is below the logo in a good looking way and without that strange white line that suddenly crosses my logo.
Could somebody please explain me how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">

</head>
<body>

    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top navbar-expand" id="myNavbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="images/testLogo.png">
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
            <div id="navbarResponsive" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="ul">    
                <li class="active"><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/**
 * Navigation bar.
 */

#myNavbar
{
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

#navbarResponsive
{
    width: 65%;
}
/*
.navbar-collapse
{
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
*/
.nav > li > a
{
    font-size: 18px
}

.navbar-brand
{
    font-size: 28px;
}

img
{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    float: right;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar > .container, .navbar > .container-fluid
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (min-width: 900px)
{
    .navbar-toggler
    {
        display:none;
    }
}

.container
{
    width: 100%;
}

button
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.bg-primary
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon
{
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Comment: How about giving the logo some padding? .. You can use "@media" to only apply this to small views.

Comment: @AhmedHammad I don't see why you are speaking about the logo. AFAIK this is unrelated. I am speaking about the dropdown menu. This is just a minimalistic example to show the issue I am facing with the menu.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.collapse{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

in mobile version

Comment: This answer goes in the good direction. But I still have that issue with that weird white line. I need to move everything lower, in order to have that line not cross my logo. I tried adding `marin-top: 100px;`  but that moves the navbar even when it is not collapsed (when it is in non-mobile veriosn)...

Comment: Adding `marin-top: 100px;` is not a correct solution in my Opinion, because you need to update this margin whenever height of your logo changes. can you send me screenshot by adding `float:left; width:100%;`.